# error with not enough storage of running m.file

Tags: matlab

```
S = xlsread('DATASEQ.xlsx','Train1','A:I');
X = xlsread('DATASEQ.xlsx','Train1','AB:AB');
X_copy = X;
X(X_copy == 2) = 1; X(X_copy == 1) = 2; X(X_copy == 3) = 1;
Z = [S X];
xlswrite('ALPHA.xls',Z,'ALP_tra1');

S = xlsread('DATASEQ.xlsx','Test','A:I');
X = xlsread('DATASEQ.xlsx','Test','AB:AB');
X_copy = X;
X(X_copy == 2) = 1; X(X_copy == 1) = 2; X(X_copy == 3) = 1;
Z = [S X];
xlswrite('ALPHA.xls',Z,'ALP_tes');

S = xlsread('DATASEQ.xlsx','Train','A:I');
X = xlsread('DATASEQ.xlsx','Train','AB:AB');
Z = [S X];
xlswrite('ALPHA.xls',Z,'ALP_tra');
```

??? Error: Not enough storage is available to complete this
operation.

Above is the code but it show the error message. May anyone can help me solve the problem?

Comment: Did you check your disk space ?

Comment: I could be wrong, but this could also mean that you don't have write permissions in that location

Answer (score 0):

It probably means you disk is full or that the data is too large to be stored in the remaining space. Although, it could just be MATLAB interpreting an Excel error thrown while saving the file as such.